# Are there any other tests demonstrating wave properties besides interference and diffraction?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, photons, quantum-optics, wave-particle-duality

Are there any other tests demonstrating wave properties besides interference and diffraction?
How about refraction? Does it show wave properties also?

Comment: You might want to start by considering what the properties of waves are and how you would go about measuring them...

Answer (score 0):

This graphic helps understanding which properties are typical for waves and which for particles:

[image: Wave particle properties.]

[The source page](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/mod1.html#c1) and its internal links are well worth visiting too.

Comment: This graphic makes clear that light is neither a wave nor a particle.  It's something entirely different, for which we have no good word for.